# Problem related to countability of sets in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a problem which was in a past prelim paper. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Any collection of disjoint non empty open sets in $\Bbb R^n$ is countable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $\Bbb Q^n$ is a countable dense set in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Brian, I got it. Can you please elaborate it a little bit..I am not seeing how to use the openness and sets being disjoint to pull it together. thank you.

Comment: By denseness of $\mathbb Q^n$ , every open set contains a point in $\mathbb Q^n$, and there are at most __________ (cardinality) points in $\mathbb Q^n$

Comment: @Kushan: Each of the open sets must contain a point of $\Bbb Q^n$, and since the open sets are disjoint, they must be distinct points.

Comment: Brian, Alex,Thanks for the help guys..

Comment: @Kushan: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ be your index set, $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be the collection of open subsets with $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset\ \forall i\neq j$. Then by the density of $\mathbb{Q}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$ \forall x\in \mathbb{Q}\ \exists!\ i:\ A_i \ni x \vee x \notin \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$$
From there on you can define a Numbering on $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ by ordering them by the first occurence of an element of $A_i$ in the counting of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ i.e. with $\phi$ the counting of $\mathbb{Q}^n$
$$\psi: i \to \mathbb{N}, \qquad i\mapsto \inf\ \{n\in\mathbb{N}| \phi(n)\in A_i\}$$
defines an injective map. The counting of $I$ is easily obtained from this.