# Show that any collection of disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Looking for feedback on my proof. Thanks!

Suppose $G = \{A_i\}_1^\infty$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. let $x$ be a point in $G$. Since each $A_i$ is open there exists a ball $B(x, \delta_x), \delta > 0$. So $\{B(x,\delta_x)\}_{x \in G}$ is an open cover for $G$ and by the Lindel\"{o}f covering theorem there exists a countable subcover $F$ of $G$. Since each ball in $F$ represents a point in $G$, $G$ is countable.

Comment: What if $G=]0,1[$ in $\mathbb{R}$ ? Is it countable ?

Comment: @Baloown You've misunderstood the question.  OP is trying to prove that the given *collection* of open sets is countable.  In your example, you've given $1$ open set and the collection $\{(0,1)\}$ is indeed countable, finite even.

Comment: @SpamIAm : I understood that, it was just a message showing that his conclusion is not correct.

Comment: Each open set contains a point of $\mathbb Q^n$ and since the sets are disjoint the rational points are unique. How many can there be?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460462/problem-related-to-countability-of-sets-in-bbb-rn

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood what I was trying to prove. I thought I was trying to prove that the collection of the points in the collection of disjoint sets is countable but rather I needed to prove that the collection of disjoint sets itself is countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a disjoint collection of open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

Each $U_i$ contains a point in $\mathbb Q^n$. Choose one and call it $q_i$. The $q_i$s are unique because the $U_i$s are disjoint.

Define the function $f$ that takes $U_i$ to $q_i$. This defines an injective function from $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ to $\mathbb Q^n$ so the cardinality of $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb Q^n$.

Therefore, $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is countable.